# Why is Amazon Route53 associating 2 IP's to our domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I'm getting complaints from around the globe that our site is down yet its fine for 99% of our users.  However, when I do a global DNS check we're being shown as having 2 IP's.

I've had one user check both IP's and only one is working for them.

Our servers are behind an ELB load balancer with one A record pointed to it.  Curious why we would be having 2 IP's?  And how to fix something like this as it seems that one of the IP's is bombing out on our users.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you show what you have added in route53?

Comment: I've simply checked 'ALIAS' for my domain's A record.  Doing this opens up a drop down selection of your current ELB's.  I chose the correct ELB which points the A record to that ALIAS value.

I'm curious, when you create an ELB they give you this long A record value.  Maybe I should explicitly point the domain's A record to that value vs. an IP.  However, not sure if that's possible since A records generally are IP's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never point an A record at an ELB. They have more than one IP (you'll see this if you `dig` against the ELB endpoint) and those IPs can change without warning.

You have more than one IP because ELBs are redundant for high availability - there's more than one server handling requests.

Comment: Is it possible to point a single IP to an ELB or use the ELB's A record value?  AWS seems to make it easy to use their ALIAS so not sure what the alternatives are.

Comment: @AdamO No, you cannot point an IP or use its A record. For an apex record (i.e. `example.com`) your only good option is an ALIAS record in Route53. For a non-apex record (i.e. `www.example.com`, `something.example.com`) you can use a CNAME pointed at the DNS name of the ELB (although ALIAS is better here).

Comment: Curious if I need to use one of their routing policies like 'Latency, Failover, Geolocation, etc'.  Also use their target health.

Comment: @AdamO No, those are all optional features and generally applicable more to someone with multiple ELBs in multiple regions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when using Route53, the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html#dns-associate-custom-elb) specifically tell you to use an A record. In fact, you can't even target the ELB alias with anything other than an A record.

Comment: This looks more like a comment on [an earlier answer](http://serverfault.com/a/617055/214507) than a response to the question.